# Sharing files between ubuntu and mac using parallel desktop

Tags: linux, macos, ubuntu, mac

I'm using parallel desktop on OS X 10.9.4 with an ubuntu 14.04 installed on. I want to share folders between these two operating system but I can not find any method doing it. I tried to change the sharing option by enabling share mac user folders with linux but it didn't help. I'm looking for another method to share folders.

Comment: did you try this one? : http://kb.parallels.com/en/114127

Comment: Yes but every time I run the installer I get this kind of errors: 
W: Failed to fetch 

but I don't have any connection problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to my parallel version. It was out of date and had lots of problems. Now I am using Version 10.0.1 and everything's solved.